# Call async_write from outside connect handler in asio

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

I use the asio library to make TCP connections. The async read/write operation is made from the handler function of async_accept.

```
        mAcceptor.async_accept(*(mConnection->Socket()),
                boost::bind(&TCPConnection::HandleAcceptForWrite, this, 
                pI8Msg, 
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
```

```
void TCPConnection::HandleAcceptForWrite(
        INT8* pI8Msg, 
        const boost::system::error_code& err)
{
    if (!err) {
        TransmitData(pI8Msg);//--> Want to call this fn from outside the handler
    }
    SocketAcceptConnection(pI8Msg);
}
```

I want to avoid the call to TransmitData (async_write) from within the handler.

I intend to call write from anywhere outside the handler of accept. When I do this I get the error - 'Bad file descriptor'

Is it always necessary to do an async write from within the handler? Please share any code sample if it can be called from elsewhere.

Comment: Note that non-owning raw pointers (pI8Msg) without size indicators are a C-code-smell and invite a big category of bugs. Consider `std:: vector<uint8_t>` or `std::span<uint8_t>` (or indeed `std::string`/`std::string_view`). Oh, and make it const-ceorrect while you're at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should provide the necessary context. E.g. what is `mConnection`? Why does `mConnection->Socket()` return a pointer? If this is a server, why does it only have a single `mConnection`?

#### Spelunking With The Crystal Ball

Using my crystal ball, I'm going to answer this question with

- mConnection is a shared pointer to an object encapsulating a socket and some connection state
- It is initialized with a new instance before accepting, always
- Therefore, unless something else shares ownership of `*mConnection` it will by definition be destroyed when `mConnection` is assigned a new instance.

The above combined, there's only one reasonable explanation: `mConnection` points to a type `T` that derives from `enable_shared_from_this<T>` so that it can share ownership with itself. You should be able to see this inside the `TransmitData` function where the shared pointer should be captured in a bind expression (or lambda) to fulfill the `async_read` completion handler.

What this does is: *keep the connection alive*, in C++ terms: extend or guarantee the lifetime until that completion handler returns. The completion handler in turn may initiate more work that shares the ownership (captures the shared pointer), and so on, until the last operation that owns the connection object loses interest and the connection object (`T`) is freed.

---

#### What To Do?

You need to keep the connection alive, even if it is idle. There are many ways. You could insert the shared pointer to it into a "connection table" (e.g. `std::vector<shared_ptr<Connection> >`). The downside would be that it then becomes hard to prune the connections: the connections are always owned, so never freed. (See `weak_ptr` below!)

In practice I'd make the connection (let's call the type `Connection` instead of `T` from now) responsible: it may decide when the other side hung up, or when there was an exchange that tells the connection to close, or perhaps even a timeout has reached.

Because the latter is very common (connections often close automatically after a set period of idle time), and also most flexible (you can set the expiration to "infinite"), let's show this:

> Side Note: during my effort to expand your snippet into something working, I noticed that weirdly the acceptor appears to live INSIDE the connection type? That makes no sense because how can you have multiple connections with a single acceptor ("server")? So I changed things around to be more typical

Note that I still keep a table of connections (`mConnections`) but instead of storing *owning* pointers (like `shared_ptr<>`) I store `weak_ptr<>` so that we can *observe* the connections without altering their lifetime.

**[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def4f1927c7b975f)**

I've taken a different approach to my usual answers, and pointed out a lot of details in comments:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

// Library facilities
namespace ba = boost::asio;
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::system::error_code;
using namespace std::chrono_literals;

// Application types
using INT8     = std::int8_t;
using Executor = ba::io_context::executor_type;
using Duration = std::chrono::steady_clock::duration;

struct TCPConnection : public /*!*/ std::enable_shared_from_this<TCPConnection> {

    TCPConnection(Executor ex, Duration timeout = 120s)
        : mStrand(ex)
        , mSocket(mStrand)
        , mIdleTime(timeout)
        , mIdleTimer{mStrand}
    {
        // cannot use `shared_from_this` inside the constructor!
    }

    tcp::socket& Socket() { return mSocket; }

    ~TCPConnection() {
        // Demo output, to understand TCPConnection shared lifetime
        std::cerr << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
    }

    void StartSession() {
        // Here we start the idle timer, so we don't disappear until that
        // expires;

        // We don't post to the strand because we assume this is the very first
        // operation on this object (there can only be 1 thread aware of this
        // object)
        StartTimer();
    }

    void TransmitData(INT8 const* pI8Msg)
    {
        post(mStrand, [this, pI8Msg, self = shared_from_this()] {
            std::cout << "TransmitData on " << mSocket.remote_endpoint()
                      << std::endl;
            // Remove the following  line to make the timout also fire if the
            // writing takes too long
            mIdleTimer.cancel(); // We're busy, not idle

            // WARNING: assumes
            // - lifetime of pI8Msg guaranteed
            // - message NUL-terminated
            boost::asio::async_write(
                mSocket, ba::buffer(std::basic_string_view(pI8Msg)),
                boost::bind(&TCPConnection::OnWritten, shared_from_this(),
                            ba::placeholders::error(),
                            ba::placeholders::bytes_transferred()));
        });
    }

  private:
    void StartTimer() {
        mIdleTimer.expires_from_now(mIdleTime);
        mIdleTimer.async_wait(boost::bind(&TCPConnection::OnTimer,
                                          shared_from_this(),
                                          ba::placeholders::error()));
    }

    void OnTimer(error_code ec)
    {
        if (ec != ba::error::operation_aborted) // cancellation is not timeout
        {
            std::cout << "TCPConnection timeout, closing " << mSocket.remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            // Timeout, let's respond by closing the socket and letting the
            // connection disappear

            // No need to post to the strand since the completion already
            // happens on the strand
            mSocket.cancel();
            mSocket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both);

            // No more async operations so shared_from_this goes out of scope
        }
    }

    void OnWritten(error_code ec, size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (ec.failed()) {
            std::cerr << "OnWritten: " << ec.message() << std::endl;
            // Error, we let the connection die

            // In case the timer wasn't canceled pre-write (see comment in
            // TransmitData) let's make sure it's canceled here
            mIdleTimer.cancel();
            // ignoring errors:
            mSocket.shutdown(tcp::socket::shutdown_both, ec);
            mSocket.close(ec);
        }

        // write was successful, let's restart timer
        std::cerr << "OnWritten: " << ec.message() << " (" << bytes_transferred
                  << " bytes)" << std::endl;

        StartTimer();
    }

    ba::strand<Executor> mStrand; // serialize execution
    tcp::socket          mSocket;
    Duration             mIdleTime;
    ba::steady_timer     mIdleTimer{mStrand, mIdleTime};
};

struct Server {
    Server(Executor ex, uint16_t port)
        : mExecutor(ex)
        , mAcceptor{make_strand(mExecutor), {{}, port}}
    {
        AcceptLoop();
    }

    void TransmitData(INT8 const* pI8Msg) {
        for (auto& weak : mConnections) {
            if (auto conn = weak.lock()) {
                conn->TransmitData(pI8Msg);
            }
        }
    }

  private:
    std::shared_ptr<TCPConnection> mConnection;
    std::list<std::weak_ptr<TCPConnection> > mConnections;

    void AcceptLoop()
    {
        mConnection = std::make_shared<TCPConnection>(mExecutor, 1s);

        mAcceptor.async_accept(mConnection->Socket(),
                               boost::bind(&Server::HandleAccept, this,
                                           boost::asio::placeholders::error()));
    }

    void HandleAccept(error_code err)
    {
        if (!err) {
            std::cerr << "HandleAccept: "
                      << mConnection->Socket().remote_endpoint() << std::endl;
            mConnection->StartSession(); // no tramsmit, just a keeping
                                         // the connection open

            mConnections.push_back(
                mConnection); // store so we can send messages later

            // optional: garbage collect the mConnections table
            mConnections.remove_if(
                std::mem_fn(&std::weak_ptr<TCPConnection>::expired));

            // Keep accepting connections
            AcceptLoop();
        }
    }

    Executor      mExecutor;
    tcp::acceptor mAcceptor;
};

int main() {
    ba::io_context mIo;

    Server srv(mIo.get_executor(), 7979);

    std::thread delayed_transmission([&srv] {
        static INT8 const message[] =
            "HELLO WORLD\n"; // NUL-terminated and static!
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(3s);
        std::cout << "Sending '" << message << "'" << std::endl;
        srv.TransmitData(message);
    });

    // mIo.run();
    mIo.run_for(10s); // timelimited for Coliru

    delayed_transmission.join();
}
```

This is a demo of a live run, demonstrating both connections that timed out as well as successfull `TransmitData` calls:

- I set the timeout to 1s,
- Transmission is done 3s after the server starts (`delayed_transmission`)
- I start one set of 3 connections early, which timeout,
- I immediately start another set of 3 connections, just in time to receive the delayed transmission
- The total server run time is limited to 10s for live demo purposes

[image]

### Text Output

For easy reference (taken from http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def4f1927c7b975f):

- Server

  ```
   ./a.out &
   HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:43672
   HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:43674
   HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:43676
   TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:43672
   TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
   TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:43674
   TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
   TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:43676
   TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
   HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:43678
   HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:43680
   HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:43682
   Sending 'HELLO WORLD
   '
   TransmitData on 127.0.0.1:43678
   TransmitData on 127.0.0.1:43680
   TransmitData on 127.0.0.1:43682
   OnWritten: SuccessHELLO WORLD
    (12 bytes)
   OnWritten: Success (12 bytes)
   OnWritten: Success (12 bytes)
   TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:43678
   TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
   TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:43680
   TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
   TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:43682
   TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
  ```
- Clients

  ```
   sleep 1
   (for a in {1..3}; do netcat 127.0.0.1 7979& done; time wait)

   real    0m1.011s
   user    0m0.012s
   sys 0m0.004s

   sleep 0.5
   (for a in {1..3}; do netcat 127.0.0.1 7979& done; time wait)
   HELLO WORLD
   HELLO WORLD
   HELLO WORLD

   real    0m1.478s
   user    0m0.008s
   sys 0m0.008s
  ```

Comment: error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::asio::basic_stream_socket<boost::asio::ip::tcp>::basic_stream_socket(boost::asio::strand<boost::asio::io_context::executor_type>&)’
         , mSocket(mStrand)
Why do I get this error? I am using boost lib 1.66.

Comment: Yeah that's old. Executors weren't so supported back then. Which is annoying because you have to remember to post/strand wrap all the time. Also, the stringview wouldn't have been supported, which just reinforces how much you need to consider using a safer type. Here's my take: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62a38e2ca27871c8 (it now has a MAXLEN because plain strlen doesn't work on INT*)

Comment: Here https://wandbox.org/permlink/ns0D7eYPybesSqOp and here https://godbolt.org/z/nYYG6rd8q you can see it compiles with Boost 1.66 (though there's not as much of a live test as on Coliru). It's already c++14 compatible.

Comment: To get C++11 compatibility you only need to rewrite the chrono time literals, and a lambda capture initializer: https://godbolt.org/z/azv3sn5T4

Comment: Welp. To get to C++03 a **lot** more work is required. And a lot more Boost :) https://godbolt.org/z/K1oYqh7Pf That was my bit of going back in time for the day.

Comment: `HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:58938
HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:58940
HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:58942
TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:58938
TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:58940
TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:58942
TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()
Sending 'HELLO WORLD
'
HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:58944
HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:58946
HandleAccept: 127.0.0.1:58948
TCPConnection timeout, closing 127.0.0.1:58944
TCPConnection::~TCPConnection()`
TransmitData is not being called. Why so?

Comment: I have copied your code as is & am running it on Ubuntu 18.04 Virtual Box. I have run the client in a separate terminal -- (for a in {1..3}; do netcat 127.0.0.1 7979& done; time wait)

Comment: As you can see the "`Sending 'HELLO WORLD '`" occurs precisely **after** all 3 initial connections (58938, 58940, 58942) timed out and were closed, but before any new connection entered.

Comment: Consider adjusting the timeouts? I chose very short times for easy demo, but it requires precise timing to be "in time". Note, my demo (both the [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/62a38e2ca27871c8) versions - for which I even split the server/client output in my answer, and the demo animation where the output is already split in separate terminals) already showed this situation (on purpose, because the idle timeout is a feature, so needs testing/demonstration)

Comment: Increasing the timeout did the trick. It works now!!

Comment: You mean, you see how it works better now :) Cheers. Good luck